# socket.broadcast.to(id).emit() doesn't work but socket.broadcast does

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets

I'm new to nodeJS and I'm trying to build a chat application. My idea is that when a user clicks on a name, he will be able to chat with that user.
I used MongoDB to keep the users' names and their id provided by socket.id.
Here is my code:

The file index.html is in the directory 'public'.

index.html, the function start() is outside of jquery because it didn't want to work like that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Tchat</h1>
  <div class="inscrire">
    <form action="" id="form">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="username">
     <input type="submit">
     </form>
  </div>

  <div id="container">

  <div id="userList">

  </div>

    <div class="chat" id="chat">
       <div class="chatHeader" id="chatHeader"></div>
       <div class="messages"> </div>
     <div>
       <form action="" id="send">
       <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="80" id="message"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="envoyer">
       </form>
     </div>

    </div>


  </div>
<script>
var socket = io();

var $currentUser;

function start(id, name){
  document.getElementById("chat").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("chatHeader").innerHTML = name;
  socket.emit('startchat', id, $currentUser);
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#container').hide();

//partie users
  function username(){
    var username = $("#username").val();

    if(username !== ''){
        $currentUser = username;
        socket.emit('new user',{user: username});
        $("#username").val('');
        $('#form').hide();
        return true;
      }
     else{
       return false;
    }

    }

 $('.inscrire').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
      if(username()){
     $('#container').show();
     $('.chat').hide();
   }

 });

//display users
 socket.on('userName', function(data){
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     if(data[i].name != $currentUser){
       $('#userList').append('<li onClick="start(\'' + data[i].socketId + '\''+','+'\'' + data[i].name + '\')">'+ data[i].name + '</li>');
       }
   }
 });


//msg part
 $('#send').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var msg = $("#message").val();
   socket.emit('message',msg);
   $("#message").val('');
 });

socket.on('msg', function(data){
  alert(data);
});
});

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


app.use(express.static('public'));

mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/chat', function(err,db){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('connected to database');

  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('new user', function(data){
      db.collection('users').find({"name":data.user}).count().then(function(numItems) { //to avoid the Promise<spending> mistake
      if(numItems == 0){
           db.collection('users').insertOne(
             {"name": data.user,
              "socketId": socket.id}
           );
           console.log('data inserted');
           callback();
         }
         else{
           console.log('data already inserted');
           callback();
         }

      });
      //envoyer le nom du user pour l'afficher
      db.collection('users').find().toArray(function(err,res){
        if(err) throw err;
        socket.emit('userName', res);
      });

    });
//partie msg

socket.on('startchat', function(id, name){
    socket.on('message', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('msg', data);

  });
});


  });



});





http.listen('3000', function(){
  console.log('server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

I wanted the user to be alerted when a message is sent by the other user, but that didn't work. If I use a socket.broadcast.emit('msg', data), and with   socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('msg', data), that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My code has no errors. It doesn't work because of the socket.id which is generated randomly, so at every new connection the id of the user changes. That's why socket.broadcast.to(id).emit() doesn't work.